# Prevent reflected XSS for date format

Tags: java, security, xss

I have a search form with a datepicker, and it is vulnerable to reflected XSS. I made up this code, and I think I successfully mitigated XSS with this solution, but I am not 100% sure.

```
String dateInput = this.getParameter(request, "dateInput");
boolean error = false; 

if (!"".equals(dateInput)) {
    // Looking for DD/MM/YYYY
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4})").matcher(dateInput);
    if(m.matches()  && m.find()) {
        dateInput = m.group(1);
    } else {
        error = true;
        dateInput = null;
    }
} else {
    error = true;
}

// dateInput is now safe from XSS
checkValidDate(dateInput)
```

Is my way of preventing XSS wrong in this case ?

Comment: Have You had the time to check the answer provided? :)

Answer (score 0):

XSS vulnerabilities are hard to eliminate. Input validation is one way to do it. I think your solution is correct. To prevent it surely use:

> [StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml(source);](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)